# build a list from an http request

Tags: json, angularjs, list

I have this code in my controller :

```
 @RequestMapping("/allU")
    public List<Utilisateur> AllU()
    {
        return UtilisateurRepo.findAll();

    }
```

in my code angularjs when I put :

```
$scope.list=$http.get("/allU");
alert($scope.list);
```

the result would object Object but not the json list.
when I make the request ( / Allu ) directly in the browser I get the json list.
I wanted to know how to retrieve this list from the http request

Comment: Try JSON.parse() maybe ?

Answer (score 2):

You are not using a promise. Use a promise like this:

```
$http.get("/allU").then(function(data) {
    $scope.list = data; //data from api
}, function(error) {
    //handle in case api fails
});
```

We have to use a promise because the ajax calls are async in nature and we need a promise to handle the data returned when the request completes.

Comment: I used your response but the result was undefined .Please help me

Comment: are you receiving any data from the api? try doing console.log(data) inside the 'then' block to find this out.